# Could there be biomes inside of asteroids?

Tags: geology, astrophysics

I don't mean "biome" in the strict scientific definition, but rather, in the broader geological sense that it is used by game designers to refer to unique environments. On earth, when people go diving into caves, or even mining down into sealed caverns, they can find caves that have their own themes. Like caves with giant crystals, or caves with stalactites or caves with ominous murky white pools.

However, the thing about earth is that it has flowing water and even life to help create these environments. Can large asteroids have liquid water or magma sealed within it to aid in the process of creating awesome environments? Do they have geological activity? Or for that matter, is life possible inside of asteroids?

What kind of biomes could plausibly exist inside of asteroids?

Answer (score 4):

Liquid substances inside asteroids are possible, because the outer shell of solid matter act as an insulator against the vacuum and cold of space. However, no matter how good such an insulation is, it won't last long enough to allow heart-like life to evolve.

It might be possible, at least in a purely speculative way, that the energy needed to sustain a biome can be supplied by radioactive decay, and that some sort of life emerges which can use radioactivity in the same way our photosynthetic organisms use sunlight, and on top of that build a food chain.

However I am pretty sure you can forget of awesome environments: black smokers at the bottom of our oceans are probably the most developed, non sun-dependent biomes on our planet, and are pretty dull when compared to anything shun by sunlight.

Answer (score 2):

Q: *"What kind of biomes could plausibly exist inside of asteroids?"*

**Simple life, microbial mats**

Suppose your asteroid has some heat and a water layer, as explained by L.Dutch. There will be no life in the water layer, at first. When Earth life formed, life needed a surface to develop on, sometimes anorganic molds like pyrite. As there is no surface or gravity inside an asteroid, biomass will need some way to attach along the "coast" (wand) of the asteroid's internal ocean. Viable life inside an asteroid could be e.g. a unicellular species and another very simple multicellular, fungae-like species, which thrives upon the remains. The [microbial mats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microbial_mat) formed by the unicellular species preserve the biomass and provide food for higher lifeforms. The fungae-like species will provide  a cohesive substance that makes the mats stick to the rock. Both life forms should be able to maintain their metabolism without oxygen. There should be certain substances available to allow the organisms to build, e.g. carbon, silicate or metal crystal "molds" to support and shape primitive life.

I actually doubt if the available time will be sufficient to let a more complicated evolution take place. Even if there would be a heat source, it won't be there eternally. Because of the small size of the asteroid, there will be no room for native "macro-animals" or complicated plant life to develop, simply because there is no room for multiple, diverse populations. The emerging of macro (animal) life will not happen imho, you'll see only few, primitive  species.

**Agriculture**

There are always engineering solutions. Animal life could be *planted* or *injected* into an asteroid and thrive in a controlled way. When the available food and/or energy is exhausted, new food can be injected, or life would need to be harvested in time.

**Asteroid life originating from a destroyed planet won't last for long**

Life could be a surviving subset of some existing evolution elsewhere. The asteroid was chipped off a larger celestial body that had abundant underground life. But in this case we're talking a really apocalyptic scenario ! There are no gentle collisions chipping off asteroids from planets. A planetary body can't fall apart, because gravity keeps it together. On a collision, planetary life will suffer mass extinction. Life must be very lucky - and living deep - to survive. But in this case, life is isolated from its context and resources: it could survive for a few thousand years.. no more..

**Immigrant life**

If life itself can be chipped off a planet and launched into space, it will depend on its resilience what happens. My favorite high-resiliance space travelling animals are [Tardigrades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade), they look cute

[image]
Tardigrade

.. but they'd need an entry, when the ocean resides underground !

Answer (score 1):

**Cadbury comet.**

[image: cadbury egg]

https://www.realclearscience.com/blog/2016/04/could_comets_contain_life.html

> According to recent research published to the journal Astrobiology,
> large comets with a radius of over 10 kilometers could contain liquid
> water at their cores. The decay of radioactive isotopes of aluminum or
> iron could supply the heat necessary to melt the inner ice. Katharina
> Bosiek, along with her colleagues Michael Hausmann and Georg
> Hildenbrand, suggest that a thick layer of dust could protect the
> core's liquid environment from solar radiation...

Your mini-biome is a comet, loaded with water and biomolecules.  Tholins from the void accumulate on its surface.  When in the outer reaches of the system, warmth would come from radionuclides could be produced by heavy elements and also more transient isotopes produced by [cosmic ray spallation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray_spallation).  When the deep freeze comes, everything hibernates.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of the current thinking, the problems are mostly geological (planetological).  If an asteroid formed as a tiny planet (which is the current assumption for the asteroids we can see from Earth), then it was never big enough to have a molten core, or for light elements to accumulate on its surface.

So there are no processes to concentrate different elements in different places; the rock is just a uniform mixture of all elements, and light elements are either bound up in minerals or evaporated long ago.  You can’t get caves because there’s no flowing water or limestone (formed from dead sea creatures), and you can’t get lava tubes because there’s no molten rock.

As a minimum requirement, then, your asteroid would have to be formed from the destruction of a mature larger planet (preferably one that had life). That being the case, you could certainly have sealed caves or even buried shopping malls if you wanted. Life might persist for a while, but after millions of years it would be far too cold, unless your asteroid happens to include a natural nuclear reactor (which is not impossible).

But generally, for life to *evolve* on an asteroid would be a stretch. Evolution requires change, and asteroids are fundamentally inert.